# installation prompt through shell script

Tags: shell, yum

I am writing a shell script to automate the installation process. Through script, I am installaing mysql, mongoDb, Java , Tomcat etc. When mysql in being installed, it halts in between asking for "do you want to proceed ? " and I have to input 'y' . How can I pass 'y' through script when this prompt comes ?

Comment: do you use apt-get? yum?

Comment: I am using:: sudo yum install mysql-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
sudo yum -y install mysql-server
```

from `man yum`:

> **-y, --assumeyes**
>
> Assume yes; assume that the answer to any question which would be
>   asked is yes. Configuration Option: assumeyes